# Dismiss ANR dialog on rooted device

Tags: adb, aosp

I have a device that is rooted that is just used to display information on the screen without user interaction, screen is just a regular screen not a touch screen.

Since my device is rooted is there a way to dismiss this dialog through an adb command or something?

ANR dialogs are coming from some external app on the device I have no control over so I cant just "fix" the issue to make the ANR go away hence why I am wondering if there is a way to just dismiss it myself

Comment: can be solved with automate apps likes macrodroid